# okhttp request / multipart image

Tags: android, request, okhttp

Ok, before you start saying that it's a duplicate and so on...
I have tried all ways I found on slack / documentations and it didn't help me out at all...and I just can't figure out what the problem is

So, these are last 2 ways I tried to make the request

```
    final MediaType MEDIA_TYPE_PNG = MediaType.parse("image/png");
    //RequestBody reqFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), loadImageFile);
    //MultipartBody.Part filePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("picture", loadImageFile.getName(), reqFile);
    //RequestBody filename = 
    RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"),loadImageFile.getName());
    RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), 
    loadImageFile);
    MultipartBody.Part filePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", 
    loadImageFile.getName(), requestBody);
```

The commented parts is a way, and the other lines is the way I am doing it now..

Here I have the interface

```
@Multipart
@POST(RestClient.API_REGISTER_URL)
Call<ResponseBody> register(@Query("name") String name, @Query("email") String email,
@Query("password") String password, @Query("location") String location,
                            @Query("latitude") double latitude, @Query("longitude") double longitude,
                            @Query("gender") String gender, @Part MultipartBody.Part picture,
                            @Part("picture") RequestBody file,
                            @Query("device_uuid") String device_uuid, @Query("device_os") String device_os,
                            @Query("push_token") String push_token, @Query("api_key") String user);
```

To be honnest, I simply can't figure out why it is not working..the response body from the server is "The picture must be an image" which makes me think that somehow it doesn't recognise the file I am sending

Any help would be apreciated, thanks .

**EDIT**
I changed the code a lil bit, another way I was trying to make it, and still something is not ok with this request...

```
RequestBody req = new MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
            .addFormDataPart("picture", loadImageFile.getName(), RequestBody.create( MultipartBody.FORM, loadImageFile))
            .build();

MultipartBody.Part part = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("picture", loadImageFile.getName(), req);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this code to send image to server with okhttp

```
     final MediaType MEDIA_TYPE_PNG = MediaType.parse("image/png");

        RequestBody req = new MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM).addFormDataPart("branchCode", branchCode)
                .addFormDataPart("upload", "profile.png", RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_PNG, file)).build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(URLs.UPLOAD_FILE)
                .post(req)
                .build();
```

Maybe problem occurs in your server side ?

Comment: It can't be on server side, on iOS it works. So it should be client side
What is branchCode var ?

Comment: Also, your image is located on the device ?

Comment: Just parameter name for server side. And the file that you want to upload

Comment: What about the URLs.UPLOAD_FILE ? Is the file path or .. ?

Comment: Server method url.

Comment: If you took a look at my interface, is a lil bit different, I need a Requestbody and a MultipartBody.Part

Comment: RestClient.getApi().register(name, email, password, location, lat, lng, gender, filePart, req,
                ANDROID_ID, URLS.DEVICE_OS, Dao.myDao().getGCM(), "user")
                .enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>()

Comment: You can add this parameter to request  request.addFormDataPart("name",name) like this

Comment: it is still not working..I get same response from server "picture must be an image" like it does not recognise it's type...this is killing me

Comment: I think I found something, and it is because of my file,loadImageFile which looks like this */storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20170725_090544.jpg*

Comment: I dont think so. Cause here is a example of absolute path of file which works fine.
 /storage/emulated/0/NokiB2B/740048.jpg